# Allow user to copy an image

Tags: android, share, copy-paste

I'm writing an app that generates an image, which I'd like to allow the user to copy so they can share it with other people.

Unfortunately, there's no copy/cut/share menu appearing when I do a long click on the image. I thought the OS would naturally do this, as it comes up in many different apps. Am I supposed to write some code before it will do this, or is there something in the layout that needs to be changed?

I've tried to google this, but the search results are taken up by various clipboard manager apps.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Have you tried saving it from Imageview to SDCard like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371803/saving-image-from-image-view-to-sd-card-android ?

Comment: For example, in Chrome on the mobile you can select something, and a bar comes up to allow you to copy it or share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OS doesn't naturally do that.  You need to implement a `OnLongClickListener` on the `ImageView`, and implement a [floating context menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu).

But if you want the user to be able to share things, I would suggest the [`ShareActionProvider`](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html) instead.