# Android Emulator Unfortunately dev tools has stopped

Tags: android

I am running Media Provider in the emulator.
I click scan scan sd card, I get -
Unfortunately, Dev Tools has stopped

The reason why I am doing this is I am trying to push images to the android emulator through file explorer and running the scan so that the images come up in the gallery.

Followed this -
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-trigger-media-scanner-api/
I got -
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED

Then read this -
[java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED on KitKat only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072489/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-not-allowed-to-send-broadcast-an)
This code does not compile as I need to use MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, paths, mimeTypes, callback)scanFile(this, new String[] {
I am not able to find an example for this.

Comment: `This code does not compile` why not? what is the problem with that code?

Comment: I have same stuation not getting anser

Answer (score 0):

There is an official bug:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62134

It is filed for KitKat but is reproducible on 5.0.1 emulator as well.