# how to update media store with out having file informaion?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Hi All
i am creating a music player app, To get list of songs i am using android MediaStore dataprovider as below

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getBaseContext().getContentResolver();
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external");
String[] proj = null;
String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE+"=?";
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3");

String[] selectoinArgsMp3 = new String[]{mimeType};
Cursor allMediaFiles = contentResolver.query(uri, proj, selectionMimeType,selectoinArgsMp3, null);
```

but i am facing challenge to update MediaStore when ever a file is added, after goggling i found the below solutions

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() )));
```

which is not working because [google is preventing it to be invoked by other apps other than system apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072489/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-not-allowed-to-send-broadcast-an#answer-24072611) as of my understanding.

- Another solution is by using `FileObserver` but this is not recursive.
- if we know the file name we can update MediaStore by using the below code but we don't have any control to get the file name because user can download a song or move a song.

  ```
  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(file.getAbsolutePath(),"mimetype");
  ```
- Last solution is to scan manually ,but scanning 3GB(by considering on an average) manually is time consuming process

So can any one please share any ideas or resource
Thanks