# While Deleting file from package directory using video adapter in RecyclerView not working

Tags: android

I am using the adapter for delete file on click event but not working i think this might preventing from deleting the file, Manifest permission is given.
I want a similar replacement of this because there are codes already done which hard to update due to this issue.

```
 try {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED", Uri.fromFile(FileUtils.APP_DIRECTORY)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Send Broadcard generate warning trace

```
 W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=12072, uid=10355
2021-04-13 12:30:52.903 12072-21602/com.******** E/sqlite3_android: [IKR-38846] ONEPLUS_NAME_PARTS_MATCH SQLITE_OK
2021-04-13 12:30:52.903 12072-12072/com.******** W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
2021-04-13 12:30:52.903 12072-12072/com.******** W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
2021-04-13 12:30:52.903 12072-12072/com.******** W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
2021-04-13 12:30:52.903 12072-12072/com.******** W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
2021-04-13 12:30:52.903 12072-12072/com.******** W/System.err:     at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.broadcastIntentWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:5684)
2021-04-13 12:30:52.903 12072-12072/com.******** W/System.err:     at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1126)
2021-04-13 12:30:52.903 12072-12072/com.******** W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:468)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA\_MOUNTED on KitKat only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072489/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-not-allowed-to-send-broadcast-an)

Comment: It similar but not work for me, and also  that's KitKat