# Can't save image in external storage in android Oreo

Tags: android, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo, android-external-storage

I want to save the image in external storage. My function works on android 5 but doesn't work on android 8.

I have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in Manifest.

```
private fun saveImageToExternalStorage(finalBitmap: Bitmap) {

         val root =
           Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()
       val myDir = File("$root/saved_images_1")
       myDir.mkdirs()
       val generator = Random()
       var n = 10000
       n = generator.nextInt(n)
       val fName = "Image-$n.jpg"
       val file = File(myDir, fName)
       if (file.exists())
           file.delete()
       try {
           val out = FileOutputStream(file)
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out)
           out.flush()
           out.close()
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           e.printStackTrace()
       }

       MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, arrayOf(file.toString()), null,
           object : MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener {
               override fun onScanCompleted(path: String, uri: Uri) {
                   Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned $path:")
                   Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=$uri")
               }
           })
   }
```

Wanted to change it with `context.contentResolver` but can't :( Hope, you will help!

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: It throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/saved_images_1/Image-3730.jpg (No such file or directory)`

Comment: This solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/40742411/10897068

Answer (score 0):

From SDK version above 23 you need to add something for URI exposure.
Extend application class and inside of onCreate() method put below code,

```
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
        builder.detectFileUriExposure();
    }
```

And in Manifest.xml, change

```
 <application
    android:name=".YOUR_APPLICATION_CLASS"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Hope, this will solve your issue.

Comment: It does't work((  `
 `<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> ` 
there is my Manifest file.

Comment: Again throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/saved_images_1/Image-3730.jpg (No such file or directory)`